# Make Body's width as a doubling of Screen with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make Body's width as a doubling of Screen.

for exmaple, 
If the width of screen(exactly, window) is 500px,
Then Body's width should be 1000px.

and I can only use HTML, CSS, and Javascript
because server doesn't let me use neither PHP nor others.

So, How to make it with CSS, and JS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use browser window units:

```
body { width: 200vw; }
```

That means, "200% of the current viewport width". You can use `vh` for "viewport height" too. That's supported back to IE9.

Note that it's probably a good idea to use "border-box" box sizing in case your `<body>` needs padding. You can set up the default for your page for that like this:

```
body { box-sizing: border-box; }
body *, body *:before, body *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought it will use a few JS code, but there was a easier and better way with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width in `%` as follows:

```
html,body{
  width:200%;
}
```

---

or using `vw` like

```
body{
  width:200vw; /*less browser support*/
}
```

This unit is only supported from `IE9`, FF30 , chrome27, Opera 23.

`vw` browser suppert @[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: @TJ `width` certainly does depend on the parent.

Comment: @Pointy Why is it that it works with a border without specifying any width for `html`..? (*this isn't an argument, just learning*)

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, but `width: 100%` means "100% of the containing box".  For the `<body>` the container is the `<html>` element, which may have padding or margin or whatever. That's why CSS resets etc. set the width of both the `<html>` and `<body>` elements. Personally I've moved to setting by "vw" and "vh" units as it seems more reliable (except in old IE of course, but I am lucky to not have to worry about that).

Comment: @Pointy not really, as far as i know. Unlike height, the browser knows the width. [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/eafddrf9/1/). Here `200%` means `200%` of what..?

Comment: @TJ the comment about `width` depending on parent width is true; in the case of the `<body>`, there's only one parent. It's usually the case that the browser default is for the `<html>` element to be 100% of the viewport width, so in that sense it works. In general though a % width value refers to the parent element, not always the viewport.

Comment: No. [**see this**](http://jsfiddle.net/eafddrf9/2/). here `100%` width means what? it's parent is an inline element for christs sake.